# Significato di "oggi sarò la tempesta"

Tags: meaning

Nella canzone "Torna a casa" viene usato questo modo di dire. C'è un altro significato o meglio una connotazione oltre a quella letterale?

È da interpretare soltanto in senso negativo (distruggerò tutto) o potrebbe essere interpretato anche in senso positivo che non riesco a stare fermo e sono molto attivo?

> E il cielo piano piano qua diventa trasparente
>   Il Sole illumina le debolezze della gente
>   Una lacrima salata bagna la mia guancia mentre
>   Lei con la mano mi accarezza in viso dolcemente 
>   Col sangue sulle mani scalerò tutte le vette 
>   Voglio arrivare dove l'occhio umano si interrompe 
>   Per imparare a perdonare tutte le mie colpe 
>   Perché anche gli angeli a volte han paura della morte 
>   Che mi è rimasto un foglio in mano e mezza sigaretta 
>  
>   Corriamo via da chi c'ha troppa sete di vendetta  
>   Da questa Terra ferma perché ormai la sento stretta 
>   Ieri ero quiete perché oggi sarò la tempesta

Comment: Potresti aggiungere il testo dove appare questa espressione?

Comment: Direi che una fonte è “La quiete dopo la tempesta” (G. Leopardi), con inversione e “personificazione”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per capire il senso di questa frase è necessario comprendere il senso del brano, in cui il cantante narra in prima persona il suo dolore per l’abbandono della sua musa ispiratrice, che prega di tornare.
Racconta il modo in cui lui è cambiato dopo aver incontrato la sua musa ispiratrice: inizialmente era un disastro e non riusciva più a muoversi, cioè a sentirsi vivo, ed era come se si trovasse intrappolato.
La musa si è presa cura di lui, lo ha aiutato ad immergersi in situazioni completamente nuove. L’ha risollevato e l’ha spinto a prendere una nuova direzione.

> In quella frase vuole esprimere quanto sia cambiato il suo modo di essere e il suo stato d’animo, prima era nella quiete, tranquillo e inesperto, in seguito all’incontro con la sua musa ispiratrice, oggi può riuscire a tirar fuori da dentro di sé un potere e un cambiamento inimmaginabili, così immensi come appunto una tempesta.

“Torna a Casa” è una canzone dei Måneskin probabilmente ispirata dal romanzo “*Marlena*” di Julie Buntin, in cui una donna di nome Cat narra in prima persona la storia della sua amicizia, da adolescente, con Marlena, che al tempo del racconto è morta.
Cat è timida e introversa, dopo il traumatico divorzio dai suoi genitori si trasferisce da Detroit a Silver Lake, dove incontra Marlena, figlia di un produttore e spacciatore di metanfetamina.
Marlena è bellissima, è forte e selvaggia ma fuori controllo, sempre alla ricerca delle emozioni più estreme, l’opposto di Cat.
E’ per questo che le due amiche, nel loro solo anno di amicizia, troveranno l’una nell’altra una sorta di completamento di sé.
Marlena inizia Cat alla vita nei modi più anomali e Cat ripercorre quell’anno di amicizia, che è stato fondamentale per la sua crescita ma a causa del quale sta ancora pagando le conseguenze delle scelte sbagliate, come la dipendenza dall’alcol.
Marlena è stata per Cat una musa ispiratrice, una sorgente di emozioni, di possibilità e di pericolo.

Nel brano non viene fatto nessun riferimento al romanzo, se non nel video dove compaiono due donne, una così debole che inizialmente non riesce ad alzarsi da terra, ma sia il brano musicale e sia il libro parlano della predita della propria musa ispiratrice che ha liberato il protagonista dalle proprie catene, attraverso la percezione profonda del senso di libertà, della creatività e della vita.

A questo [link](https://www.unamusicapuodire.it/significato-canzone-torna-a-casa-maneskin/) si può trovare il commento della canzone con i parallelismi al romanzo.

Comment: ...Ok. Fatemi solo aggiungere che nessuna parte di questo contesto è evidente per qualcuno che legga solo il testo della canzone.

Comment: Chi è l'autore dell'articolo che citi? Si può considerare affidabile o è solo un'ipotesi come un'altra?

Comment: @DaG “unamusicapuodire” è un sito dedicato al significato delle canzoni, il parallelismo tra il brano e il romanzo nel sito è ben spiegato, infatti i racconti appaiono praticamente speculari. Ho ascoltato alla radio uno stralcio di un’intervista del cantante del gruppo, Damiano David, che alla richiesta di chi fosse Marlena ha riposto che è l’ispirazione del gruppo, la musa che tira i fili di ogni loro brano, in quanto è la rappresentazione della loro libertà.

Answer (score 3):

La mia impressione è che si tratti di un riferimento abbastanza chiaro alla [*quiete prima della tempesta*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quiete_prima_della_tempesta) ("the calm before the storm"), per cui che significhi circa "ieri sono rimasto calmo, ma oggi mi arrabbio sul serio".

Concordo che non abbia davvero molto senso nel contesto degli altri versi, ma purtroppo non so che dire. Magari il verso piaceva troppo e hanno voluto includerlo anche se mancava di coerenza con il resto della strofa.

Comment: (Opinione personale) non conosco l'artista né la canzone, ma onestamente nei versi che leggo non vedo nessun nesso, sembrano tutti messi lì solo per far rima. Ripeto, opinione personale.